# C# Outlook AddIn Appointment event 'ItemSend' does not cancel properly

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in

I am developing a little Outlook AddIn using C# and I cannot get this AddIn to properly cancel the ItemSend process. 
I'm hereby thinking of the following scenario:
Consider this small AddIn:

```
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        ((Outlook.ApplicationEvents_Event)this.Application).ItemSend += new ApplicationEvents_ItemSendEventHandler(ThisAddIn_ItemSend);
    }

    void ThisAddIn_ItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("You can't save it, it's in the past!");
        Cancel = true;
        return;
    }
```

Now, when I try to change an existing appointment item, I change some values of it when opened in the appointment window, like location, etc. On hitting the "Send" button in the appointment window, the message in the textbox appears as expected. But the problem is that Outlook ignores this cancellation and already saves the changes. The only thing that happens is that the appointment window is not closed. But when simply closing the window without saving explicitly you can see that Outlook has already accepted your changes made to the appointment item.

Is this an intended behaviour? Can Outlook be stopped from saving changes even though the Cancel parameter has been changed to "true"?

Comment: Isn't there some ItemSending event? ItemSend looks like an action after Sending the actual item.

Comment: unfortunately this is the only 'Send' related event that can be accessed in Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationEvents_Event that will work for all items, as much as I can see so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use [`Application.Inspectors.NewInspector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.inspectorsevents_event.newinspector.aspx) event and latch onto the [`AppointmentItem.Send`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff865990.aspx) event.

According to the `AppointmentItem.Send` MSDN documentation - the expected behavior is that the send doesn't occur when `Cancel = true`, the inspector window is left open and the changes are still saved - just not sent to attendees.

If you want to cancel the Save - you need to latch onto the [`AppointmentItem.Write`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff865085.aspx) event to cancel saves prior to sending.

Comment: unfortunately I need the AppointmentItem inside the event handling method to be able to validate it. AppointmentItem.Write does only have one parameter, its ref bool cancel.

Comment: You just need to store a reference to it in a wrapper class. Take a look at the [`InspectorWrapper` howto](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff973716.aspx). You need to keep a property reference.